# Print a result without a preceding square bracket in R

Tags: r

```
x <- 5+2
print(x)
[1] 7
```

How to suppress `[1]` and only print `7`?
Similarly for characters:

```
y <- "comp"
print(y)
[1] "comp"
```

I want to remove both `[1]` and `" "`. Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You can `cat(x)`, but what exactly are you trying to accomplish? there are better ways to write formatted output in R if that's what you are after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `cat`, it is possible

```
cat(x, '\n')
7
```

Or for characters

```
cat(dQuote(letters[1], FALSE), '\n')
"a"
```

Comment: Let me update my question a little bit: what if for characters? For example, in the output `[1] "comp"` I want to remove both `[1]` and `double quote`. Is this possible?

Comment: @Gada how do you want to print that

Comment: `cat("a", "\n")` doesn't print quotes. I have separated the 2 strings because there might be several strings to print but this `cat("a\n")` also works. Just don't forget the ending newline.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed it. I was trying to comment on the OP's comment.